# Custom Level Logging in SLF4J

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2, slf4j, slf4j-api

In my project logging is working perfectly fine. Using Slf4j for logging.
Sample is as follows:

```
 import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
 import org.slf4j.Logger;
 public class MyClass{
   private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

   public static void main(String...args){
     logger.error("error log...");
   }
 }
```

we have used log4j2.xml for logging configuration.
Now my requirement is to make a custom level log "VERBOSE" having int value 150. I am trying hard but it seems difficult or I dont know if slf4j has flexibility to provide the custom level logging.
Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Log4j2 API has that capability. SLF4J does not. However, while not equivalent, you could add a VERBOSE Marker to the events and filter on that.

Comment: thank you @rgoers for replying and confirming as I was also in doubt whether SLF4J has the capability to do the same.